# Would like to get numerical (lower [and upper?]) bounds for $p$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

This question is an offshoot of this [earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2672275).

Let $\sigma(z)$ denote the sum of divisors of $z \in \mathbb{N}$, the set of positive integers.  Denote the *abundancy index* of $z$ by $I(z) := \sigma(z)/z$.

If $N={p^k}{m^2}$ is an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with Euler prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$, then it is somewhat trivial to prove that
$$3 - \dfrac{p - 2}{p(p-1)} = \dfrac{3p^2 - 4p + 2}{p(p-1)} < I(p^k) + I(m^2) \leq \dfrac{3p^2 + 2p + 1}{p(p+1)} = 3 - \frac{p - 1}{p(p+1)}.$$
Now, setting $x := 3 - \bigg(I(p^k) + I(m^2)\bigg)$, we have the simultaneous inequalities
$$\dfrac{p-1}{p(p+1)} \leq x < \dfrac{p - 2}{p(p - 1)}$$
resulting in the inequalities
$$\begin{cases}
{
(p - 2) > xp(p-1) \\
(p - 1) \leq xp(p+1).
}
\end{cases}$$

Notice that it is known that
$$\dfrac{57}{20} < I(p^k)+I(m^2) < 3$$
so that we know that
$$0 < x < \dfrac{3}{20}.$$

We now solve the inequalities one by one.

[WolframAlpha computation for $(p - 2) > xp(p - 1)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+(p+-+2)+%3E+xp(p+-+1)+for+p)

> Solution is
>   $$\dfrac{(x+1) - \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x} < p < \dfrac{(x+1) + \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}$$

[WolframAlpha computation for $(p - 1) \leq xp(p + 1)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+(p+-+1)+%3C%3D+xp(p+%2B+1)+for+p)

> Solution is
>   $$p \in \bigg(-\infty, \dfrac{1 - x - \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}\bigg] \bigcup \bigg[\dfrac{1 - x + \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x},\infty\bigg)$$

Now, this is where the computations start to get messy.  Can I ask for some help?

Basically, I would like to get numerical (lower [and upper?]) bounds for $p$.

Comment: For starters, [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maximize+((x%2B1)%2Bsqrt(x%5E2+-+6x+%2B+1))%2F(2x)+subject+to+0+%3C+x+%3C+3%2F20) says that
$$\dfrac{(x+1)+\sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}$$
has no global maxima in the domain $0 < x < 3/20$.

Comment: Additionally, [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+((x%2B1)-sqrt(x%5E2+-+6x+%2B+1))%2F(2x)+subject+to+0+%3C+x+%3C+3%2F20) says that
$$\dfrac{(x+1) - \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}$$
has no global minima in the domain $0 < x < 3/20$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easily seen that$$\dfrac{(x+1) - \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}<2, \dfrac{1 - x - \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}<2$$so your conditions reduces to$$\dfrac{1 - x + \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}\le p<\dfrac{1+x + \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}$$
then, one can see that the lower bound and upper bound differs by $1$ and both are unbounded in the given range of $x$. That is, there can be only one prime $p$ for any given value $x$.

Answer (score 1):

To get an approximation to $\dfrac{(x+1) + \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}$ you can write $$\dfrac{(x+1) + \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x}=\frac 12+\frac 1{2x}+\frac {\sqrt{(x-3)^2-8}}{2x}\\=\frac 12+\frac 1{2x}+\frac 12\sqrt{\left(1-\frac 3x\right)^2-\frac 8{x^2}}$$
The last term forces $0 \lt x \lt 3-2\sqrt 2$ or $x \gt 3+2\sqrt 2$  When $x$ gets small this blows up like $\frac 1x$.  When $x$ gets large the square root is less than and close to $1$, so we can bound this by $1+\frac 1{2x}$

Comment: Just a minor comment, @RossMillikan:  Shouldn't that be
$$\dfrac{(x+1)+\sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 1}}{2x} = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\bigg) + \dfrac{\sqrt{(x-3)^2 - 8}}{2x}?$$

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris:  Yes, I dropped a factor $2$ from the first two terms.  Fixed.